Read excel with same column names with pandas
I am trying to convert an excel to csv. The excel has the following headers -
DATE,FIELD1,FEEDER BRANCH,50,100,200,500,1000,2000,FIELD2,50,100,200,500,1000,2000,FIELD3,50,100,200,500,1000,2000

As seen, some columns are repeated. On loading the excel using pandas, it appends an index number to it. Eg. On repetition, 50 becomes 50.1, 100 becomes 100.1 ... and so on.
How do I load the excel without this suffix. I want the col headers as is  so that when writing as csv, the same is retained.
Current code:
def pandas_csv_from_excel(source):
  dir_and_file = source.split('/')
  filename = dir_and_file[len(dir_and_file) - 1].split('.')
  if not ((filename[1]).lower().startswith('xls')):
    return source

  csv_filename = f"{os.path.join(os.path.dirname(source), filename[0].lower())}.csv"
  location = os.path.dirname(source)
  df = pd.read_excel(source, index_col=None)
  df.to_csv(csv_filename, index=None)
  return csv_filename


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78929046/pandas-2-x-alternative-for-mangle-dup-cols-with-read-excel

Convert Excel to CSV, save the file from Excel as CSV.

save the file from Excel as CSV -> there is no GUI.

Try using header parameter as None
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel('path/to/file.xlsx', header=None)

df.columns = df.iloc[0]  # Set the column names to the first row
df = df[1:] 

df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)


Tried this. Dint work.

You can use openpyxl to get the first row (i.e. columns):
import openpyxl
dataframe = openpyxl.load_workbook("excel path")
sheet  = dataframe.active #or you can define your current sheet index
col_names = [cell.value for cell in sheet[1]] #get first row as a list

Now you can define col names after reading excel:
df = pd.read_excel(source, index_col=None)
df.columns = col_names

or better way:
df = pd.read_excel(source, index_col=None,header = None)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.drop(df.index[0])

